# Rails debugger exits automatically after some interval, and Ubuntu terminal tab hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, byebug

I am using byebug for debugging my rails application.Debugger stops but continues automatically after some time interval and gives this:

[5188] ! Terminating timed out worker: 5378

- Worker 0 (pid: 5959) booted, phase: 0

and also when sometimes it makes terminal hang.
Please help!

Comment: Are you using `puma` server in gemfile?

Comment: yes, but using it for production mode =>group :production do
  gem 'puma' end

Comment: Just comment it out. and make sure its to un comment it before push code or deploy code, probably this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Did that help you out ?

Comment: Yes :) , That worked.Thanks.

Comment: would you allow me to write answer for it. And accept that for future SO searchers.?

Comment: yes sure, Actually I am new here so can you explain steps for this " allow me to write answer for it."

Answer (score 5):

I could solve that problem by changing worker_timeout in config/puma.rb.
It seems that problem is already solved in new rails 6.1 projects using these lines:

```
# Specifies the `worker_timeout` threshold that Puma will use to wait before
# terminating a worker in development environments.
#
worker_timeout 3600 if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"
```

Default is 90 seconds.

The puma documentation says:

> Verifies that all workers have checked in to the master process within the given timeout. If not the worker process will be restarted. This is not a request timeout, it is to protect against a hung or dead process. Setting this value will not protect against slow requests.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/puma/Puma%2FDSL:worker_timeout